# Synology ssh transmission command

Tags: sh, synology, transmission-daemon

I'm using Synology NAS and Package Center 'Transmission'(not docker). I want make sh script for transmission.

so typing

```
root@NAS:/volume3/NAS# transmission-remote
-ash: transmission-remote: command not found
```

I can't use transmission-remote command.

How to use transmission command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed transmission, to have a look on it. I also have some other packages installed, these are installed in /usr/local

[image]

When you follow the transmission symlink and have a look in the bin directory you find the desired scripts:
[image]

You can start the script by: ./transmission-remote